# Difference between these two string assignments

Tags: c++, string, variable-assignment

New to Programming and C++.
I was watching a tutorial and the person did this:

```
//method one
string wholeName = yourName.assign(yourName);
```

What is the difference from this method and what is more beneficial?

```
//method two
string wholeName = yourName;
```

Also, if they have two different implications and reasons for use, what are they?

Edit: I saw this method used in this video: http://youtu.be/Rub-JsjMhWY?t=25m42s

Comment: It is easy to guess what the second one does. The first one looks nonsensical.

Comment: Method one should be `string wholeName; wholeName.assign(yourName);` imho

Comment: The first one doesn't make sense..

Comment: This is why we do not learn C++ from random videos on the internet.

Comment: The first one is almost certainly undefined behavior.

Comment: Just for clerical reasons, what does string.assign() do anyway?

Comment: @MolotovBeaver: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/assign Think of it as a configurable version of `operator=` for strings.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an attempt to shrink the capacity of `yourName` to the size of the string before assigning it to `wholeName`, but it's pretty nonsensical. I wouldn't expect this to do anything useful that the following doesn't do:

```
yourName = yourName;
wholeName = yourName;
```

i.e. nothing